# collapsible Sidebar from Bootstrap 4+

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, sidebar

I am trying to build a collapsible sidebar from Bootstrap 4+. I have got a code created from [Bootstrap 3.3.7](https://www.codeply.com/go/ecE6qHNBOC) but when I converted it [Bootstrap 4+](https://www.codeply.com/go/NxRJkobuAg), the UI is not as it was showing in Bootstrap 3.3.7. I am not so conversant with the HTML styling and sincerely seek help from somebody who have done this.

Comment: A code example could help. Also how it looks before and after converting to bootstrap 4.

Comment: *I have got a code* - please show it then in a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @Pete I have provided my `codeply` workings in the link

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same vertical side bar in Bootstrap 4 as you achieved in Bootstrap 3, simply add the class "flex-column" to the div with your "nav" class.

```
<ul class="nav flex-column" id="menu">
```